# Max. number of connections per file

Tags: multithreading, apache, nginx, download, connection

I have 2 servers: 1 on apache and 1 on nginx.

I want to limit the max number of connections/parts/threads per downloading file from my servers.
I want to do so that 1 user can download as many files as he want in the same time, but with limit: max 4 connections per 1 file.

How can I do that?

thanks for info!